# pyppeteer- How to goto next page by clicking sub link (href) in a page using python pyppeteer

Tags: python, pyppeteer

below code which launches the browser and that site for URL

```
 from pyppeteer import launch

 browser = await launch({"autoClose":False,'headless': False})
 page = await browser.newPage()
 await page.goto('some url')
```

after loading page, I need to click on a hyperlink on the same page to go to next page

which method I should use and how?

1. await page.click('selector')
   2.xpath
   3.query selector

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

from pyppeteer import launch

browser = await launch({"autoClose":False,'headless': False})
page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('some url')
# select some element hyperlink
element = await page.querySelector('a.some_class')
# apply click function to our element
await element.click()
```

Comment: Please don't just write the code, explain it to the OP